# How can I ensure that all subprocesses are killed after calling a Python function using Pool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-unittest

My question regards the generation and killing of subprocesses when using Pool from the multiprocessing module.

Consider two modules, `multiproc.py` and `unit_test_multiproc.py`:

Module `multiproc.py`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def say_hello(num, name1, name2):
    return ', '.join(['Hello', name1, name2, str(num)])


def say_hello_4procs():
    with Pool(4) as p:
        lst = p.starmap(say_hello, [(0, 'Jack', 'Jill'),
                                    (1, 'Batman', 'Robin'),
                                    (2, 'Janeway', 'Picard'),
                                    (3, 'Marco', 'Polo')])
        p.close()
        p.terminate()
        p.join()

    return lst


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__name__)
    lst = say_hello_4procs()
    print('\n'.join(lst))
```

Module `unit_test_multiproc.py`:

```
import unittest
import multiproc

print('__name__')


class TestCases(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_1(self):
        lst = multiproc.say_hello_4procs()
        print('\n'.join(lst))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running `multiproc.py` directly gives the expected output:

```
__main__
Hello, Jack, Jill, 0
Hello, Batman, Robin, 1
Hello, Janeway, Picard, 2
Hello, Marco, Polo, 3
```

However, when I run `unit_test_multiproc.py`, I get this unexpected behavior:

```
__main__
__parents_main__
__parents_main__
Hello, Jack, Jill, 0
Hello, Batman, Robin, 1
Hello, Janeway, Picard, 2
Hello, Marco, Polo, 3
.
-------------------------------------------
Run 1 test in 0.172s

OK
```

It seems that there are some sub-processes being created but NOT killed.  How can I fix this?  I've read that calling `close()`, `terminate()`, and `join()` from pool should kill all sub-processes.  But obviously I am missing something.

I've gone through the debugger, and I've discovered that those `__parents_main__` strings are being printed from within `multiproc.py` but that it's the name of the actual testing module.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why do you think there are sub-processes that aren't killed? It's not clear from the output you included that any processes in the pool are still alive.

Comment: The procesess are in fact killed. I have since verified. It looks like what happens is that if you're multiprocess function is called from a sub module that it kicks off subprocesses from the parent module all the way down. Is this as intended? Is it just that best practices would be to make your multi-process function main?

Comment: That would be pretty inconvenient for me.